# Movie about a boy transported to a virtual island via a Gameboy-style device

Tags: story-identification, movie

I see there's a recent question on here about a book that sounds similar to this, but this was definitely a movie, most likely a made-for-TV movie, that didn't seem futuristic at all.

The plot featured a blonde boy with a 90s hair cut who was home alone or something and was pretty hooked on his gameboy or gaming thing and gets transported to some kind of hokey island with a cool set design and some puppets or something. He's with some kind of mentor?

This was definitely a kids movie and not scary or suspenseful at all. This has been in the back of my mind for years and I've never been able to identify anything about it that would lead me to the answer. I've searched "list of Nickelodeon made-for-TV movies" and "list of Disney made-for-TV movies" and I don't think it's in either of those, but it's possible I overlooked it.

Comment: Sounds sort of like a passage from 'The Beach' with Leonardo diCaprio. At one point in the narrative he's sparring with the drug dealers on the island and imagines himself in a video game. In the film it all turns a bit 'catoony' at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the TV series *[Pirate Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_Islands)*? A boy and his two siblings are transported into their PC game and spend the series trying to return home. Don't think there are any puppets though.

Answer (score -4):

Could it have been Spy Kids 3: Game Over?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could explain what portions of Spy Kids match up with the question, or why you think it's the right movie.

Comment: Having (unfortunately) seen Spy Kids 3, I can assure you that the way the asker described it is **not** how they got into the game world at all, so no, it's not.